# Unable to connect to xbee device in xctu

Tags: serial-port, xbee, zigbee

I have 3 xbee receiver devices connected to Ubuntu on port `ttyUSB0`, `ttyUSB1`, `ttyUSB2`. Out of these 3, device on `ttyUSB2` stops working after every 2-3days. When I open xctu, it shows below error:

[image]

Could not find device on port /dev/ttyUSB2. Error initializing xbee device parameters. Connection timeout. Could not read device information.

When I type ls /dev or lsusb, I can see all 3 devices connected and all the 3 serial ports but the device on /dev/ttyUSB2 doesnt respond. When I unplug it and plug it back, it starts operating normally. But again after 2-3 days, it stops responding.

Can anyone please suggest what could be the issue.

Comment: It can be many different things. If all three devices are the same I would bet one of them (or the corresponding serial port adaptor) is faulty. Have you tried switching devices to other ports to find out where the problem is (serial port or connected device)?

Comment: @MarcosG. Yes, I have tried changing the serial port of the 3rd xbee device as this is the only device creating issue  but no success. But I havent tried swapping the port of 3rd device with 2nd device to check if the 2nd device also shows same issue. Will do that and update

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turned out another program (Cura / Creality Slicer, in my case) was *intermittendly* checking the serial ports for connected devices, which (I assume) interrupted serial communication for XCTU.
Closing the other program solved the issue.